# Why "impregnable" is an auto-antonym?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read this [online](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/25/books/review/a-nose-for-words.html?_r=0):

> “Impregnable” was an autoantonym, too. It was like a snake that ate its own tail.

Why "impregnable" is like a snake that eats its own tail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's talk about that snake. From Wikipedia:

> The **[ouroboros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros)** is an ancient symbol depicting a serpent (or dragon) eating its own tail. The ouroboros often symbolizes **self-reflexivity** or cyclicality, especially in the sense of something constantly re-creating itself.

Now let's examine the definitions of *impregnable*, where we can find a little self-reflexivity. From [Wiktionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/impregnable):

> *adj*. Too strong to be penetrated.
>       *adj*. Capable of being impregnated.

These two meanings almost seem clash with each other, thanks to the different ways *im-* can be used as a prefix. With an adjective, im- can mean "not" or "unable to be":

> **impossible** (*adj*) not possible

but with a verb, *im-* can mean "to make":

> **impassion** (*verb*) make passionate

In everyday usage, *impregnable* is most often used to mean "unable to be penetrated," and is usually applied to fortified or defensive structures, or perhaps to logical arguments:

> The concrete bunkers were impregnable.
>   The security analysts believed the firewall was impregnable.
>   The prosecutor believed his argument was impregnable and the defendant would be convicted.

It would be harder to find usages where *impregnable* means "capable of being impregnated"; typically, a word like *fertile* is used instead. But the author is marveling at the way the two definitions seem to conflict on the surface – not at the typical ways the word used.